# Vite manifest not found at: C:\xampp\htdocs\lolabout\public\build/manifest.json

Tags: json, laravel, web, laravel-livewire

"Vite manifest not found at: C:\xampp\htdocs\vrsweb\public\build/manifest.json"
"Start the development server"
"Run `npm run dev` in your terminal and refresh the page."

When i try to acces login or register of my project website

I tryied to "Run 'npm run dev' on a second cmd line besides the one's that got the server on and it says this:
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npm run dev
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: so, the error is pretty basic, you need to run `npm run dev` or `npm run build`, at least once, so you build the assets... you have to install NPM if you don't have it install in windows, or if using WSL, then use that therminal, not CMD or PowerShell

Comment: Already try it... is says "'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: `npm run dev` is not how you install `npm`... Follow the docs here: https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm, or search "Install npm windows" on Google.

Comment: @JoãoPimentel as I said on my comment: _"you have to install NPM if you don't have it installed in windows"_, so please, INSTALL npm......

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!!!!
First i installed Node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

INSTALLED THE LATEST VERSION!

Then went to cmd, put it on the folder of the project with cd, and then runned "install npm"!

Just right after it i did the "npm run dev" AND IT WORKED FINE FOR ME!!!!
Ty